# How to get text from temporary element

Tags: javascript, selenium, text, protractor, end-to-end

I have HTML:

```
<div class="p-login-info" ng-show="loggedOut()">My text.</div>
```

And in javascript:

```
var e = element(by.className('p-login-info'));

e.getText()
.then(function(text){
    var logoutText = "You have been log out.";
    expect(text).toMatch(logoutText);
    console.log("============= "+text);
 });
```

And my console log doesn't contain anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the test failing? If yes, what is the error?

Comment: It is saying 
expect '' to be "You have been log out."

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a [`textToBePresentInElement`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElement) expected condition:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var e = element(by.className('p-login-info'));
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(e, "You have been log out."), 5000);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it, and with

`element(by.css("a[ng-click*='globalActions.logout()']")).click()`
          `.then(function(){`

           `var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;`
            `var e = element(by.className('p-login-info'));`

          `browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(e, "You have been` `log out."), 4000);`
`)};`

I'm still getting  **Error: Wait timed out after 4465ms** - no matter how is the timing big, the amount of ms in the error message is always bigger.

Comment: @Yte thanks for coming back with it, this could mean either that this is not the element containing the text, or the text of this element doesn't contain `You have been log out.`.